# Sum Quantity and Price in Tables

Tags: jquery, sum

I have 4-5 dynamically created Tables with PHP

```
<table class="table11">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="quantity">2</td>
      <td class="price">20</td>
      <td class="sum_one">40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="quantity">1</td>
      <td class="price">30</td>
      <td class="sum_one">30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="total_quantity">3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="total_sum">70</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table11">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="quantity">1</td>
      <td class="price">10</td>
      <td class="sum_one">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td class="quantity">2</td>
      <td class="price">10</td>
      <td class="sum_one">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="total_quantity">3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="total_sum">30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to sum all prices in the table and show in total_sum.

I have tried this:

```
var sum = 0;
var quantity = 0;
var sum1 = 0;
$('.price').each(function() {
    var price = $(this);
    var q = price.closest('tr').find('.quantity').html();
    sum += parseInt(price.html()) * parseInt(q);
    quantity += parseInt(q);
    sum1 = 0;
    sum1 += parseInt(price.html()) * parseInt(q);
    price.closest('tr').find('.sum_one').html(sum1);
});

console.log(sum);

$('table.table11 tr:last-child').find('.total_sum').html(sum);
```

Which doesn't work, in the console it logs the sum, that is correct but in the tables it doesn't change.

How can I update the sums in each of the Tables with the relevant sum of price?

As I dynamically delete rows I would like the totals to update accordingly.

https://jsfiddle.net/qfjes1zj/ .... i will all sum table by table and not complete sum at end. every table sum.

Comment: This line is too much work `var q = price.closest('tr').find('.quantity').html();`.  Why not just do `price.closest('.quantity').html();`

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup because closest does not look at siblings so that would not work...

Answer (score 1):

Why is the td called *total_sum*

```
<td class="total_sum">30</td>
```

and then you update *total-price*?

```
$('table.table11 tr:last-child').find('.total_price').html(sum);
```

It should be just

```
$('.total_sum').html(sum);
```

Comment: thanks, i have to fast write. but it doesnt work... https://jsfiddle.net/qfjes1zj/ .... i will all sum table by table and not complete sum at end. every table sum.

Comment: The code works correctly, but your Fiddle doesn't include jQuery library, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: ok. i will tried. but the sum in the next table include the sum from the first table with my code.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var sum = 0;
var quantity = 0;
var sum1 = 0;
$('.price').each(function() {
    var price = $(this);
    var q = price.closest('tr').find('.quantity').html();
    sum += parseInt(price.html()) * parseInt(q);
    quantity += parseInt(q);
    sum1 = 0;
    sum1 += parseInt(price.html()) * parseInt(q);
    price.closest('tr').find('.sum_id').html(sum1);
});



$('table.table11 tr:last-child').find('.total_price').html(sum);
});
```

Calculation should be executed after page has been loaded